# SVN post-commit update error (Can't create temporary file from template / permission denied)

Tags: linux, svn, post-commit-hook

My post-commit hook is:

/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/html/mysite/ --username myusername --password mypassword --no-auth-cache  >> /var/www/html/mysite/foo.txt 2>&1

After performing a commit, my post-commit hook outputs to foo.txt the following:

Updating '/var/www/html/mysite':
svn: E000013: Can't create temporary file from template '/var/www/html/mysite/.svn/tmp/svn-XXXXXX': Permission denied

Any ideas?? Must be something related to permissions. It used to work, but something happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check if you have the permission of /var/www/html/mysite/

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @user2644136 You can use the ls command to show the directory permission, but I think maybe you can login with root.

Comment: Using SSH, I can perform an update using "sudo" before de "svn up" in the "mysite" directory. The problem comes when trying to do the update with the "post-commit" hook (I suppose its not the same user I use when performing updates via SSH).

Comment: @user2644136 You can check [this link](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/34952-post-commit-hooks-not-running.?p=103872&viewfull=1#post103872)

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks man! It was hard not to find the solution at Google, but luckily I did so txs to you. Cheers!

Comment: I have added some info and examples to your answer, as it is the first google hit for this SVN error message.

Comment: @user1853181 where did you put your infos?

Comment: Unfortunately the edit was rejected. I'm not sure if you can see it in the suggested edits.

Comment: I had the same problem. The </path/to/html/.svn/tmp> directory permissions had changed to root somehow. chown proper_user:proper_user /.svn/tmp fixed it. Would anyone know WHY this happens?

Answer (score 8):

When this happens to me (svn 1.7.14), I usually just have to create the tmp directory and retry the command:

```
mkdir /var/www/html/mysite/.svn/tmp
```

Comment: This simple trick did it also for me. Afterwards "svn cleanup" (and any other svn command) worked again.

Answer (score -1):

For all Linux Machine Users

Its file permission issue run this particular command in linux terminal.

```
 chmod -R 0777 /var/www/YourProjectName
```

Comment: maybe you might want to change the owner to `www-data:www-data` (`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/YourProjectName`) instead of giving everyone read and write permissions to the folder and all files.

Comment: Never do this as this will give fully control of your files to the outside